# Parsing Apache Error Logs For Unique Errors

Tags: regex, linux, apache, parsing, logging

I have some unruly apache error logs that I would like to parse through and get unique errors.

`[Fri Sep 21 06:54:24 2012] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ] PHP Fatal error:  <error message>, referrer: <url>`

I think I just want to chop the lines at the "PHP Fatal" section, discarding the first half and running the second half through uniq.  My goal is to identify all the errors, but there are too many lines to look through each manually, due to to the many duplicate errors.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Try `grep -o '\[error\].*$' file | sort | uniq`

This will show only thing which match the regex (rather than the whole of a line which contains the match).

Then sort puts similair entries next to each other, so that uniq can ensure there are no duplicates.

If you want to remove the client bit before sorting / uniq'ing, use
 `grep -o '\[error\].*$' file | sed 's/\[client.*\?\]//'  | sort | uniq`

Answer (score 2):

To analyze `/var/log/apache2/error.log` use

```
sed 's^\[.*\]^^g' /var/log/apache2/error.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

This will

1. cut the date at the beginning of each line like:

   [28-Aug-2012 11:20:24 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: test in /var/www/... on line ...
2. count unique lines
3. sort them by occurrence

> source: [strictcoder.blogspot.de](http://strictcoder.blogspot.de/2012/02/linux-count-unique-error-log-entries.html)

---

If you create new logs, you could configure php beforehand:

Set [`ignore-repeated-errors`](http://php.net/manual/de/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-repeated-errors)`= On` in php.ini or add `ini_set('ignore-repeated-errors', 1);`  to your php scripts

This will stop php from logging an error more than once i.e. error messages caused by same line in same script.

> source: [php error log, how to remove the duplicates/find unique errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12607878/1069083)

(but this doesen'i help on analyzing existing logs)

Comment: `uniq` only detects unique entries when they are next to each other. If you just want to collapse repeated results this is fine, otherwise, you'll want to sort the results first `sed 's^\[.*\]^^g' ./error-log | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`.

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed -r 's/(.*)(PHP Fatal error)/\2/' logfile | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

regex parsing string could be `ERROR.*` (test it on regex101.com)

Below command will ensure it searches case insensitive

```
grep -ori 'ERROR.*$' filename | sort | uniq
```