# php error log, how to remove the duplicates/find unique errors

Tags: php

Is there a way to search the error log for only unique errors. Reason being I have a lot of duplicate errors and don't want to miss the rare ones.

How would I go about writing a custom script which parses the error log, and filters out all of the duplicates excluding the datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [`ignore-repeated-errors`](http://php.net/manual/de/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-repeated-errors)`= On` in php.ini or add `ini_set('ignore-repeated-errors', 1);` to your php scripts

This will stop php from logging an error more than once i.e. error messages caused by same line in same script.

Comment: That is not a solution if you have to analyse an existing log that was created without that setting on

Answer (score 6):

To analyze `/var/log/apache2/error.log` use

```
sed 's^\[.*\]^^g' /var/log/apache2/error.log | sort | uniq -c
```

This will

1. cut the date at the beginning of each line like:

   [28-Aug-2012 11:20:24 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: test in /var/www/... on line ...
2. sort them according to numerical value
3. finds **and counts** unique lines

> source: [strictcoder.blogspot.de](http://strictcoder.blogspot.de/2012/02/linux-count-unique-error-log-entries.html)